# XSLT transformation from any XML to a list of name-value xml elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform an XML document (actually, I need to transform ANY xml) into a list of elements that store the value as element value and the name of the original node as an attribute called "name" like:

```
<rootNode>
    <element name="first">value1</element>
    <element name="try">valueX</element>
<rootNode>
```

being the original:

```
<a>
    <first>value1</first>
    <try>valueX</try>
</a>
```

Comment: 1) Oh god, why? Seriously, this sounds like a really bad idea. 2) It's not very hard to do, you must have tried yourself. Have you?

Comment: I have, but couldn't get it to work. as for the first part, why, is a great question, I tried to convince the rest of the developer team to use the XML as they came, but they want to show it in a table, inside a little jspx in this particular format, and as I'm not the architect, I just have to do it...

Comment: If you want to visually represent XML, changing it into *other* XML first and then changing *that* XML into HTML sounds like shooting yourself in the foot. Especially since you do not change the structure of the document, but only the names of the elements. That's awfully redundant. BTW, your sample does not define how to handle nesting. For all I understand, the output would start with `<element name="a">` and not with `<rootNode>`.

Comment: "*I need to transform ANY xml) into a list of elements*" That's not too difficult to do. However, you do need to address the question of nesting raised by Tomalak. Turning a nested document into a list of element name-value pairs **removes information permanently**. You will not be able to reconstruct the original document.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with it being a seriously bad idea. It is 100% the opposite of what most people want ... turning good XML into bad form. Then again, it is simple if there isn't any hierarchy you are trying to replicate. You want a structure like this:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="a">
            <rootNode>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </rootNode>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
            <element>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </element>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces:

```
<rootNode>
   <element name="first">value1</element>
   <element name="try">valueX</element>
</rootNode>
```